# Двойной возврат по ссылке href=./

Tags: html, laravel, href, octobercms

В октябрь смс рисую ссылку  <0а href="./" >Ссылка назад<0/а>. То есть она возвращает на страницу назад. На той странице опять та же ссылка. Только теперь она уже не срабатывает без обновления. Урл вида: сайт.ру/первый/второй/третий
Не пойму, как сделать чтоб продолжать возвращаться выше по урл при клике на ту же ссылку? Там хешируется что-то?

Comment: history.back() не подходит, так как нужно переходить на страницу выше, а не предыдущую

Comment: Собственно простыми методами не обошлось. Дело в том, что href="../" срабатывал только один раз, затем на уровне выше отказывался работать, пока не обновишь страницу. Реализовал через js. Просто для

Comment: ..кнопки каждый раз устанавливал href="полный путь сайта на уровень выше".

Answer (score 0):

Измените значение href в вашей ссылке, как я указал ниже:

```
<а href="../" >Ссылка уровень выше</а>
```

Пояснение: "../" ведёт на папку выше, в то время как "./" ведёт в корень.

*P.S.: Air, я перед ответом лично проверил что это работает, каким образом в моём сообщении нет ответа на вопрос?*